# Bootstrap Carousel Component Cause Blank Page

Tags: reactjs, carousel, react-bootstrap

It could be some silly question but I'm stuck here.

I created `Header` and `Footer` components which working fine. I also created another component called `Slider` and there is `Carousel` component inside it.

Since I put `Slider` between `Header` and `Footer` inside `App.js` page went blank. When I delete `Carousel` component inside `Slider` and put some `Container` and `Box`, page came back with `Header` | `Box` | `Footer`.

This is the example Carousel from Bootstrap website which I tried to see on my work:

```
import React from "react";
import { Container,Box } from "@mui/material";
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel';


function Slider() {

    return (
        <div>
            <Container sx={{  float: "left",}}>
                <Box sx={{ width: 300, height: 300, backgroundColor: 'blue', '&:hover': { width: 500, height: 500, backgroundColor: 'primary.secondry', opacity: [0.9, 0.8, 0.7],},}} />
            
            </Container>
        
            <Carousel>
                <Carousel.Item>
                    <img
                    className="d-block w-100"
                    src="holder.js/800x400?text=First slide&bg=373940"
                    alt="First slide"
                    />
                    <Carousel.Caption>
                    <h3>First slide label</h3>
                    <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
                    </Carousel.Caption>
                </Carousel.Item>
                <Carousel.Item>
                    <img
                    className="d-block w-100"
                    src="holder.js/800x400?text=Second slide&bg=282c34"
                    alt="Second slide"
                    />

                    <Carousel.Caption>
                    <h3>Second slide label</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                    </Carousel.Caption>
                </Carousel.Item>
                <Carousel.Item>
                    <img
                    className="d-block w-100"
                    src="holder.js/800x400?text=Third slide&bg=20232a"
                    alt="Third slide"
                    />

                    <Carousel.Caption>
                    <h3>Third slide label</h3>
                    <p>
                        Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.
                    </p>
                    </Carousel.Caption>
                </Carousel.Item>
            </Carousel>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Slider;
```

and this is the App.js

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "./Header";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Slider from "./Slider";


function App() {
  return (
    <>

    
  <Header/>
  <Slider/>
  <Footer/>

    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**UPDATE:**

I guess the problem explanation is this console error:

react.development.js:209 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This caused by having two node_modules folder. One inside a project folder one outside of a project folder and I was trying to install all things to outside one. Noobie mistake.

Deleting outside one and using inside one solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For `react-bootstrap` to work, the required [stylesheet](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction#css) would need to be imported in `App.js`:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

But there could be other reasons within `Header` and `Footer` causing these not to render.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Even if I import stylesheet it doesn't work. I also tried material UI carousel made by npm. That also give blank page.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-material-ui-carousel?activeTab=readme